# array initialisation with 0 in c

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

I made an `int` array in C and initialised it with 0 as follows -

```
int f[10000] = {0};
```

My program demanded me to reinitialise this array in the end of the loop. So, I performed this step -

```
f[10000] = 0;
```

But this didn't worked. I even tried

```
f[10000] = {0};
```

but got error in it too. Ultimately, I had to use `memset`. Can anyone help as in where is the error occurring and why?

> EXTRA INFO - I USED ideone.com FOR CODING PURPOSE

For the reference, here is the complete code -

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int t, n, k, f[10000] = {0}, c[10000] = {0}, i, v, count = 0;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while (t--) {
        scanf("%d %d", &n, &k);
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            scanf("%d", &v);
            if (v == i) {
                f[i] = 1;
            }
            c[v]++;
        }
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            if (!f[i] && c[i] >= k) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n", count);
        count = 0;
        memset(f, 0, 10000);
        memset(c, 0, 10000);
        //f[10000] = 0; this didn't worked
        //c[10000] = 0; this didn't worked
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Arrays are zero-based in C: f[10000] = 0; will overflow the array. The maximum array index is 9999 in your case. Also, your loop counter starts at one and you will always step over the first array element. Also, your loop counter could try to access an array element out of bounds. memset should work

Comment: @clarasoft-it `memset` will not work properly, as it takes no account of the data element's size.

Comment: @Weather-Vane yes, you are right!!! should use 10000 * sizeof(int). Thanks for pointing it out :-)

Comment: "My program demanded me to reinitialise this array in the end of the loop." How did it do that?

Comment: @clarasoft-it it should be `memset(f, 0, sizeof f);`

Comment: @clarasoft-it I am not aware of internal working of `memset` but the code above worked fine. For the reference, I was solving https://www.codechef.com/problems/STUDVOTE. Maybe this happened because the array size I used was way larger than it was required and `memset` didn't have to reach the limits. I'm not sure and any clarifications would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C, initialization is not the same as assignment, although both use `=`.

```
int foo[3] = { 0 };
```

means "make `foo` an array of three integers, all initialized to zero", but `foo[3] = 0;` means "set the fourth element of `foo` to zero". Clearly different.

And since `memset()` works in bytes, this:

```
memset(f, 0, 10000);
```

is wrong, it should be:

```
memset(f, 0, sizeof f);
```

as long as `f` is a proper array as in your code.

Also beware that very large arrays as automatic variables might not be very portable.

Comment: Keep in mind that sizeof is a compile time resolved operator and will not work if, for example, you use it on an array passed in as a parameter to a function.

Comment: @javey That's what I meant by "proper array", arrays cannot be passed as themselves to functions (they decay to pointers), which is well-known.

Comment: @javey, you are right that `sizeof` can be and is evaluated at compile time under most (but not all) circumstances.  But any way around you can rely on it to evaluate to the size of the type designated by its operand.  The trick is being certain you know what type that is, including knowing that arrays are *never* passed as function arguments, even when the function declaration appears to suggest otherwise.

Comment: @John Bollinger fair point. I'm curious under what circumstances sizeof is not evaluated at compile time.

Comment: @javey, `sizeof` is evaluated at runtime when its operand is or has a  variably-modified type.

Answer (score 1):

If you did like this

```
int f[10000] = {0};
```

then

```
f[10000] = 0;
```

is wrong since index starts at 0 in C so you are writing outside the array bounds.

Answer (score 0):

[As previously mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38775768/315052), you cannot assign to an array. However, you can assign to a `struct`.

```
struct foo { int f[1000]; } f = {};
```

Then,

```
f = (struct foo){};
```